# reinstall of OS after decreasing memory

Tags: ram

Do I need to reinstall OS after decreasing memory (RAM)?
Originally I had 8GB while now only 4GB.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
`Linux p6-2315el 3.13.0-76-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Depends who you ask, how fast you want it to process... with lower ram on 64bit it will run slower the lower ram on 32bit.  It depends on what you preference is.

Comment: did you take the RAM out on purpose, or did it 'disappear'?

Answer (score 6):

No you don't have the reinstall the OS but i will suggest add a swap partition as you might need it.

Comment: Do you mean I have to adjust the swap partition due to changed configuration?

Answer (score 5):

No. You don't need to reinstall your OS.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to reinstall Ubuntu , every thing will run fine. It will automatically detect that you have upgraded your ram.